# Navigating a record using a Listbox and RecordsetClone property

Tags: vba, ms-access

Navigating a recordset using a listbox I previously used this code with success. However today, I am getting a runtime error.
I don't really fully understand `RecordsetClone` and and how to effectively use it together with a listbox on a form. The listbox is bound to One Column and
Has its RowSource set to: `SELECT [ID], [Gender] AS Sex, [Location], [AccountsManager] FROM tblAccounts;`
Then the code is below:

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
Me!ListBox1 = Me.txtBoxID
Me.txtCredit.Value = DSum("[InputSum] - [UsedSum]", "[qryUsers]", " 
[AccountManager] = '" & Me.txtAccountManager.Value & "'") 'txtCredit is an Unbound textBox
End Sub

Private Sub ListBox1_AfterUpdate()
With Me.RecordsetClone
.FindFirst "ID=" & Me.ListBox1
If Not .NoMatch Then Me.Bookmark = .Bookmark 'Error here
End With

End Sub
```

Upon selecting a list item, I get runtime error 2473.
Can someone please guide me through?

[image]

Comment: I get error 3077 until I change code to: `Me.Listbox1.Column(0)` then it works perfect.

Comment: @June7 Is that on the line `.FindFirst "ID=" & Me.ListBox1`? If so, I still get the same error 2473.

Comment: What exactly is in the event property? Should be `[Event Procedure]`.

Comment: @June7 There is a list of TextBoxes and one listbox on the Pop-up form. Its record source is the `tblAccounts` Users should be able to select record on the list and see the corresponding fields displayed in the textboxes. The some textboxes are bound to the same record source but one text boxes is unbound.

Comment: Didn't answer question. What is in the listbox AfterUpdate event property?

Comment: @June7 Pardon me I am calling a module that has this line:

`Me.txtCredit.Value = DSum("[InputSum] - [UsedSum]", "[qryUsers]", "[AccountManager] = '" & Me.txtAccountManager.Value & "'")`
I tried putting a stop at this module and it seems to be working. It looks like I will have to redefine my main table table to include a field for the unbound text box then just bound it instead to make life a bit easier. Thank you as always! I will update my OP.

Comment: That makes no sense to me. How is that connected to what is in listbox AfterUpdate event property? However, if you have a fix that's what counts.